# Connection Refused on MongoDB Docker Container from Flask Docker Container

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask, dockerfile

I have two docker containers.

- Flask app
- MongoDB

Flask app has a DockerFile that looks like this.

```
from alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

CMD ["app.py"]
```

This is how I am connecting my local Mongo (Not Container) from Flask

```
mongo_uri = "mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/myDB"
appInstance.config["MONGO_URI"] = mongo_uri
mongo = PyMongo(appInstance)
```

MongoDB is running on the container in `mongodb://0.0.0.0:2717/myDB`.

This is obvious when I run Flask container with local mongo uri which is `mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/myDB`, everything works. But It shouldn't work when I try to connect the Mongo Container in the same way. Coz Flask container doesn't know anything about that Mongo Container.

My question is - how do I connect this Mongo Container with Flask Container so that I can query Mongo container from Flask Container.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was you, I would use **docker-compose**. 

**Solution just using docker** 
You'd have to find out the IP address of your mongo container and put this IP in the flask configuration file. Keep in mind that the IP address of the container can change - for example if you use a newer image. 
Find IP address: 
`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id`

**Solution using docker-compose** 

In your docker-compose file you'd define two services - one for flask and one for mongo. In the flask configuration file you can then access the mongo container with its service name as both services run in the same network.

*docker-compose.yml:* 
`services:
    mongo:
        ...
    flask:
        ...`

*flask configuration:* 
`mongo_uri = "mongodb://mongo/myDB"`
In this example `mongo` is the name for your mongo service.

Comment: Your solution is perfect. I am studying on writing docker-compose file. But I'm not being able to put instruction for an existing mongo docker container. Would you please elaborate?